# UINavigationController, pop to webview

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a navigationcontroller and want to pop back to the rootview (uiwebview),

There seems to be some slight delay (empty view) before web page is shown, almost as if the webview is loading again. How do i prevent this? Is there a way of telling the rootview to not unload when i push a new view?

**EDIT:** Clarification, i push/pop UIViewControllers with UIWebViews in them

**EDIT:**

My RootViewController http://www.codeshare.io/3KrPH

My UINavicationController handler http://www.codeshare.io/KIn8g

Comment: Please share existing code that you are using and shows you have attempted this yourself.

Comment: Maybe you are loading the webview content in the viewwillappear and it makes the webview to reload when going back.

Comment: I do it on loadView, should i put it in init() instead?

Comment: You are completely correct, i do some dumb stuff on view WillAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your reload the webviews every time you will show the rootviewcontroller, with a boolean you can by pass the reload once it's loaded.

Comment: Yep, as diegomen pointed out, i added the pages on viewWillAppear, which i really shouldn't be doing. Thanks for the help!